# Parse Json received from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have controller that is mapped by "/createRoute-getPlaces".
When I'm calling it, it returns massive:

```
[{"id":1,
...
"name":"Test",
...
"description":"Test",
...},
{"id":5,
...
"name":"Test2",
...
"description":"Test2"
...}]
```

Where is '...' there are othe objects.
**How do I parse this in my js to json object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) I belive

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) might help you there.